# Python Linux Kiosk using keyboard module

Tags: python, linux, exec, keyboard-events, kiosk

I'm trying to build a simple kiosk, using a Python script with the keyboard module to detect keys on the keyboard and execute commands accordingly. The problem is that Python keyboard module on Linux runs as root, but my kiosk apps run as an unprivileged user. Once I start up the kiosk app from my Python script, the focus is somehow stolen and the keyboard events are no longer registered by my Python script. Here is the code:

```
import os
import keyboard
white True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        os.system('runuser tux -c \' firefox localhost\'')
    else:
        pass
```

Using this code firefox is launched successful and I have the localhost app running. But now this same Python script is not reachable anymore. `'q'` to quit does not work.

I also tried using the `subprocess.call` module instead of the `os` module but that did not work either.
I also tried using `sudo` or `su` to execute the command but that also did not work.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Or maybe propose an alternative approach to the current method I'm using?